# How to extract values from a bundle in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

How can I extract the values "Stock", "Currency" and "Euro" from this bundle ?

This is my output for bundle.toString() :

```
Bundle[{Stock:Currency=Bundle[{_=Euro}]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toString()` output is a bit ambiguous, but this might work:

```
Bundle subBundle = bundle.getBundle("Stock:Currency");
String euro = subBundle.getString("_");
```

If this works, then `euro` will contain the string `Euro`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast respond! I tried .getBundle("Currency") before, which didnt work. The part with ":" in the bundle confused me.